# Java DXA 2.2 with Tridion docs java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot detect ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl while preparing Pagemodel Object

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, tridion-docs, dxa2.2

We are upgrading java dxa from dxa-1.8 to dxa-2.2

I am facing problem generating PageModel object as it is failing to map viewdata information, 
we mainly need Pagemodel content information , could someone please help/guide me on this.

```
It is failing at instantiating pagemodel on DefaultModelBuilder class.
line no 297
Class<? extends ViewModel> viewModelType = viewModelRegistry.getViewModelType(mvcData);
```

error is:

```
13:20:04.800 [http-nio-9090-exec-6] DEBUG c.h.k.controller.IshController - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot detect ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework, controllerName=Page, actionName=Page, areaName=Ish, viewName=GeneralPage, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot detect ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework, controllerName=Page, actionName=Page, areaName=Ish, viewName=GeneralPage, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getViewModelType(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:168)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.instantiatePageModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:297)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildPageModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:258)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createPageModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:62)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.GraphQLContentProvider.loadPage(GraphQLContentProvider.java:199)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.AbstractContentProvider.getPageModel(AbstractContentProvider.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.getPageModel(Unknown Source)
    at c.h.k.repository.content.providers.IshContentProvider.getPageModel(IshContentProvider.java:99)
    at c.h.k.repository.content.providers.ContentService.getPageModel(ContentService.java:86)
    at c.h.k.controller.IshController.getPage(IshController.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting issues because i was not using dynamic documentation module here,

And this is Tridion docs implementation so after addition of[dynamic documentation moduler](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/2.2/webapp-java/dxa-module-dynamic-documentation/pom.xml) and update of few references to dynamic documentation module classes now I am able to get the pagemodel object.